# Invalid File Handle Opening Directory in Mounted Drive to UNIX

Tags: unix, windows-services, mount, nfs

There is one windows service trying to access mounted drive in UNIX, but it always fails

The mounting command is:

```
mount -o anon -o mtype=soft \\xx.xx.xx.xx\u01\sourceData H:
```

However, the windows service is throwing exception:

> Invalid File Handle Opening Directory

Further investigation,

Now, I perform the mount command in the cmd, even though the drive is mounted successfully, it could not be accessed correctly.

I could only view the contents of the files, but I could not open, or copy the files.

The error pop up saying:

> The remote computer refused the network connection.

This is weird. Last time was ok.

Any idea?

Thanks experts!

Comment: Have you ever tried to trace the system call with https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx on the service? It will ease the life to trouble shoot the problem.

Comment: How can a *Windows* service mount a *UNIX* drive?  Are you running Cygwin, or WINE, or what?

Comment: Running on Windows Server 2008, the windows service is a custom code built using C++.

Comment: The mount command is in:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754350.aspx

Comment: Further investigation info updated. This is weird